# Laravel validation max number according to another field (+2 from period_starts

Tags: laravel

help me to solve this

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'period_starts' => 'required|numeric|digits:4|min:2010|max:'.(date('Y')),
    'period_ends' => 'required|numeric|digits:4|gt:period_starts',
]);
```

Is there any way to validate period_ends greater than period_starts but only max +2 not allowed more

Comment: there are no built-in solution for this use case, so a custom validation rule have to be implemented to check for the optionally null parameter before actually compare values.

Comment: could you give me an example, please

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to add 2 two your gt:period_starts
and then use before_or_equal:new period_starts rule
reference

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-before-or-equal

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'period_starts' => 'required|numeric|digits:4|min:2010|max:'.(date('Y')),
    'period_ends' => 'required|numeric|digits:4|gt:period_starts|max:'.(($request->period_starts)+2)
]);
```